Blown in Attic Insulation
I recently purchase a 1957 ranch style home with blown in insulation within the scuttled attic.
Attached are picture I collected of the blown in insulation and it looks like cellulose. However, I found a banner that references Johns-Manville Spintex “blown” home insulation. Should I be concerned that it contains asbestos?
banner in my attic
picture of insulation
picture of insulation
 picture of insulation
 picture of insulation
 picture of insulation

Not unless you plan on disturbing it or rolling around in it without a mask.  Leave it alone and it will leave you alone.

It looks deep, but looks and being deep are two different things.  Quite possible it is not deep enough for today's standards.  Today you might want double than Yesterdays standard, depending on your location's weather.

Thank you for the responses! I appreciate it.

A web search has shown that Spintex is rockwool and does not contain asbestos.
Spintex (According to Asbestorama, scroll below the pic.)
However the definitive method of knowing what is in the product is to have it tested.
